Flutter/Dart: Display One product per Widget, with data retrieved as JSoN From backend API
Respected Experts,
I am trying to get my hands on Flutter and building a demo app that needs to do the following:

Retrieve Product data from a backend API. The GET API returns multiple products in single call

Render the data of all the Products one by one, based on scrolling by the user.


I have been able to accomplish #1 i.e. retrieve the data from API and display it as single list.
Here's my rendering code:
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('My Product List'),
  ),

   body: ListView.builder(
   //  physics: const PageScrollPhysics(),
 //   scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    // this give the length of item
    itemCount: productList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ProductCard(content: productList[index]);
    },
  ),
);

}
The Product Card Looks like:
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Card(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Column( // this is the column
      children: [
        //      SizedBox(
        //        height: 200,
        //        width: 20,
        //        child:
        ListTile( //ListTile Supports Leading, Title/Subtitle, Trailing
          leading: Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.red),
          title: Text(content.productHeading),
          subtitle: Column (
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text('Author: ${product.owner}'),
              Text('${content.productBody}')
            ],
          ),

          trailing: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text('Rate Me: '),
              Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.orange),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        //   )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);

}
This code renders the list of all the products. However, what I need to render one product per page (or widget In Flutter parlance) i.e. the Product 1 on page/widget 1 and let the user scroll to next product on next page/widget.
I tried certain variations by using SizedBox, PageScrollPhysics, scrollDirection etc. So, that's why code is bit unclean.
My questions are:

Can I achieve the desired results with ListView? If yes, what am I missing here
Which other widget, I should use to achieve the desired result?

PS: I am using Intellij as my IDE and running the app on Connected Chrome (web). Also, I am more of a backend person.

You can use the PageView widget. It behaves very similarly to ListView and even has a PageView.builder constructor.

Thanks Code on the Rocks and Jostin Akkara for your inputs. I was able to achieve the desired results by using the sample code from Flutter's PageView page and the PageView.builder constructor. The productList.map was throwing error for me. I will post my complete code when I am done.

One QQ: My initState methods fetches the products from REST API by using Future and it also initializes the TabController  _tabController = TabController(length: 7, vsync: this). I want the length to be dynamic based on the no of products returned i.e. the length should be equal to productList.length. How can I achieve the same. Thanks.

You can achieve this using a PageView: Below is a sample code
Widget build(BuildContext context) 
{ return Scaffold(
 appBar: AppBar( title: Text('My Product List'), ),

body: PageView( 
controller: pageViewController, 
scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, 
children: productList.map((listelement){ 
return ProductCard(content: listelement); 
}).toList(),
)
);
}


Based on the inputs from @Code on the Rocks and @Jostin Akkara, I am sharing the  working code that achieves the desired results. The code is based on PageView with logic provided in Page View Docs.
The caveat is about initializing/re-initializing Tab Controller.
Initialization of rendering code:
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchProducts();
    print(contentList.length);
    _pageViewController = PageController();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 99, vsync: this);
    //Length needs to be be dynamic i.e. contentList.length
    //At this stage we don't know the length of content
    //So, we have reiniialized the TabController in fetchProduct method
    //If the initial length is less than reinitilzed length, an exception is thrown.
    
  }

The fetchProduct:
    Future<void> fetchProducts() async {

        Uri uri = Uri.parse('http://localhost:8080/rest/products');
        try {

          final response = await http.get(uri);
         if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            List<dynamic> jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
            setState(() {
              productList = jsonData.map((data) => Product.fromJson(data)).toList();
            });
          } else {
            // Handle error if needed
          }
        }
        on Error catch(e) {
          print(e);
        }
//Reinitialize Tab Controller, since we know the size
        _tabController.dispose();
        _tabController =  TabController(length: productList.length, vsync: this);
    
      }

The Renderer
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Stack (
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    children: <Widget>[
  PageView.builder(
      controller: _pageViewController,
      onPageChanged: _handlePageViewChanged,
      itemCount: productList.length,

    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return productCard(content: productList[index]);
    }
    ),
      ContentPageIndicator (
        tabController: _tabController,
        currentPageIndex: _currentPageIndex,
        onUpdateCurrentPageIndex: _updateCurrentPageIndex,
        isOnDesktopAndWeb: _isOnDesktopAndWeb,
        productCount: productList.length,
      ),
    ]
    );
  }

The supporting methods are same as provided on the Page View Widget Docs. So, skipping them.
Product Renderer
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column( // this is the column
          children: [
            ListTile( //ListTile Supports Leading, Title/Subtitle, Trailing
              leading: Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.red),
              title: Text(product.productHeading),
              subtitle: Column (
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text('Author: ${content.author}'),
                  Text('${product.productBody}')
                ],
              ),

              trailing: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text('Rate Me: '),
                  Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.orange),
                ],
              ),
            ),
           ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Now, I am wondering what are the best Practices to re-initialize Tab Controller. Shall I make the fetchProduct() sync and wait for it to fetch the products. This way I will have the size to initialize Tab controller.
